# How to test whether the parent's function has been called from child?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am passing a function to child component and on click in child, it goes to parent function to execute. I want to write a test case but it is unable to find the function.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  closeModal = () =>{
    this.setState({
      showModal: false
    });
  }

  render(){
   return (
      <>
        {showModal
          && (
            <ChildModal
              data={modalValue}
              cancelHandler={this.cancelHandler}
              submitHandler={this.submitHandler}
              closeModal = {this.closeModal}
            />
          )}
      </>
  }
}

class ChildModal extends Component{
   render(){
     const { cancelHandler, submitHandler, closeModal } = this.props;
     return(
       <div id={modalId}>
         <button type="button" id="close" onClick={() => 
                                         closeModal()}>
         Cancel</button>
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

## Test Function:

```
  const closeModal = jest.fn();  
  const wrapper = shallow(<ChildModal {...props} {...state} />);
  const button = wrapper.find('#close');
  button.simulate('click');
  wrapper.update();
  expect(closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [jest.fn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestfnimplementation). It will return new, unused mock function.

```
const mockedFunc = jest.fn();
```

Now, while creating `ChildModal`, you need to pass `mockedFunc` in `closeModal`.
Once you simulate `click` event on `Modal`, you need to check below condition:

```
expect(mockedFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

If `expect` return true, parent function was called.

Comment: It worked, the issue was I was not passing the mock function into the child component as suggested in above answer.